# UILabels as part of UIView subclass do not initiate

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, custom-controls

So, I have a subclass of UIView that I want to contain two custom UILabels. The subclass of my UIView initialises as "it should", however, the UILabels do not (I have tried with ordinary UILabels as well, but that does not work either.). The is no trace of any print statement and they are not displayed. They do work fine on their own, when I put one directly onto the storyboard.

I do not know were to turn, nor what is wrong. I have scoured the internet for days now. Please help this beginner...

```
class MainscreenButton: UIView {

 @IBOutlet var icon: LAUILabel!
 @IBOutlet var info: LAUILabel!

 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
     super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
     print("mainscreenbutton requiredinit")
 }

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
     print("mainscreenbutton frameinit")
 }
}
```

Comment: You are overriding UIView initializers instead of UIlabel initializers? It is not clear in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well.

they should initialize.. you just need to give them a frame/bounds/position. IBOutlet implies storyboard or NIB, so make sure that you set the class in the storyboard or nib and connect the IBOutlet. then give the labels constraints + text and they should appear.

if you wanted to do something like `var icon = LAUILabel()` and then in the initializers do like `icon.frame = CGRect(... blah whatever)` or programmatic constraints for autolayout that should work too

Do note that in my code though I have this as the storyboard/nib initializer

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

}
```

not sure if its just not picking up on it bc of slightly different method signature

you also many need to call `label.layoutIfNeeded()` if you don't give them explicit width constraints (maybe you only give it an x). Because it'll be initialized with a 0 width if theres no text and no width or no leading/trailing x constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are doing UIView as button but if u want to do like that just flow this:

**1) Create UILabel Custom class**

```
class LAUILabel: UILabel {

    //you can even define some params like @IBOutlet images ...

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        updateUI()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        updateUI()
    }

    private func updateUI() {
        backgroundColor = .red
        textColor = .green
        numberOfLines = 1
        textAlignment = .center
    }

}
```

2) Create your  MainscreenButton

```
class MainscreenButton: UIView {

 @IBOutlet weak var icon: LAUILabel!
 @IBOutlet weak var info: LAUILabel!

 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
     super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
     print("mainscreenbutton requiredinit")
 }

 override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
     print("mainscreenbutton frameinit")
 }
}
```

3) Connect your UI with your custom classes
you will go to storyboard or Xib files and drag a view  go to Identity Inspector then insert the name of your class 'MainscreenButton' in the custom class after that drag UILabels inside that view and change the custom class from the identity inspector like before 'LAUILabel' then link the the labels with the corespondent UI its should work.

4) Otherwise you can create the label without storyboard like this:

```
class MainscreenView: UIView {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        print("mainscreenbutton requiredinit")

        let icon = LAUILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50), size: CGSize.zero))
        icon.text = "icon"
        icon.sizeToFit()
        addSubview(icon)

        let info = LAUILabel(frame:  CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50), size: CGSize.zero))
        info.text = "info"
        info.sizeToFit()
        addSubview(info)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("mainscreenbutton frameinit")

    }

}
```

Comment: I suppose I want to do "3)", because I want it to be a short text label above an icon, which is reused some times in the app. This app is done on android, and perhaps I am stuck in the ways of android developing...

Anyhow, it does not work. The label-outlets for some reason are nil, the "mainscreenbutton" is not however. The inspector does say that the outlets are connected.